# $r in React Devtools

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I was looking for how to get an instance in the console of the component being inspected in React Devtools. I stumbled on [this blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/08/03/new-react-devtools-beta.html) from 2015, and happened to see that in the upper right hand corner it says **$r in the console**. I tried it and it worked.

[image]

But in my version of the devtools I don't see this, however $r still works to get the instance of the component.

[image]

I'm wondering why I don't see this anymore, and/or what setting I need to configure to make sure this is visible (I'll probably forget). Has this feature been deprecated or just forgotten about? It's very useful to inspect properties of the component that are not props or state.